# Using SetInterval to change CSS background url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

I'm really getting frustrated with this... I have a solution where the CSS background element originates from a webservice. Currently the system uses HTML to refresh the entire page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
```

...

```
body {
    background: url('/wallspace/getfile.php?width=gt:1919&height=lt:1700') #1D1F21 top left no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This works fine enough, except it triggers an entire page refresh, which is jarring to the end users. I'd like to perform this task in javascript so it's a more elegant transition and doesn't flicker the entire page every x seconds

I cannot figure out why this SetInterval function is not working

```
  $(window).load(function() {          
    var path=encodeURI('/wallspace/getfile.php?width=gt:1919&height=lt:1700');
    $("body").css("background", "url('default-bg.png')");
    setInterval(function(){ callback() }, 5000); 

    function callback() {
      // This works so callback is definitely being triggered
      //alert("here");

      // This only works the first time --is there caching happening?
      $('body').css('background', "url('" + path + "')");
    }
 });
```

Basically, the callback function is being called at the specified interval but it's not changing the background element. I verified this by calling alert and they are being triggered.

The url of the webservice fetches a random image based on the querystring it recieves in the GET request but it seems like the JQuery is only making the call once and then caching the first response because the background image only changes the first time and then never again until the page is fully refreshed.

Comment: Try adding a timestamp to the end of the URL to avoid caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since path is declared and not being changed, the CSS isn't being changed either.
So in CSS, you arn't changing your URL, thus not changing your background.

Try and add random data, like a timestamp:

```
$('body').css('background', "url('" + path + "&tx="+(new Date()).getTime()+"')");
```

---

The reason it works the first time is simple, you are changing

```
background: url('default-bg.png');
```

to

```
background: url('/wallspace/getfile.php?width=gt:1919&height=lt:1700');
```

Which is a change.

The second time you change

```
background: url('/wallspace/getfile.php?width=gt:1919&height=lt:1700');
```

to

```
background: url('/wallspace/getfile.php?width=gt:1919&height=lt:1700');
```

Which doesn't change a thing. And since it doesn't change, it does not trigger a reload.

Comment: Excellent.. for a simple test I generated a random number between 1 and 100 for each request and that worked but obviously that strategy is flawed in the long term. It doesn't look like there's a native GUID generator in Javascript and your solution looks to be about the best way to generate a unique url. Thanks!

Comment: Using a random number gives you a chance you get the same number which is not 100% what you want, so using the current time is the way to go since that's álways different.

Comment: Yup, absolutely. The random number thing was just for a quick test; I wanted to use a GUID but in lieu of that, your answer accomplishes the same result. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
setInterval(function(){ callback() }, 5000);
```

with

```
setInterval(callback, 5000);
```

Comment: Although more succinct and better practice, it's logically no different.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right, I read it wrong and thought he was invoking the function doing `setInterval(callback(), 5000);`. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Rory McCrossan and @Robbin 'Roboroads' Schepers

Ensuring the url is different everytime prevents the caching and properly gets a random image!

```
   function callback() {
      // Url needs to be unique to prevent caching
      var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

      $('body').css('background', "url('" + path + "&rand=" + num + "')");
    }
```

You guys here on Overflow are great!

[image]